# share extension showing only under the more section in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8-share-extension

I had an application in which i made a share extension.But My point is For the first time it is coming only in the more section of the `UIActivityViewController`.not coming independently like Facebook or twitter.Can anybody help me on this issue to find out anything missing in my configuration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. New extensions don't show up until the user adds them, which they do by clicking "more" and enabling them. New extensions don't show up automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I had also one doubt that how to go with provisioning profile and bundle id in extension plist.can u help me?when i am creating separate profile it shows me error of embedded item having different bundle id..